# Deploy Spring Boot application on AWS (Elastic Beanstalk) that uses RDS - Application does not start

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application connected to a MySQL database. This has already been installed on AWS and entered into Spring's properties file. The connection works and I can also connect to it with my workbench. But my problem is that the application does not run on AWS. I changed the SERVER_PORT to 5000 (also in the properties) but I can't get the APP to run

The AWS log file:

[image]

[image]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.backend</groupId>
<artifactId>SYFALL</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SYFALL</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

application.properties file:

```
server.port = 5000
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://AWS_DATABASE:3306/syfall
spring.datasource.username = xxx
spring.datasource.password = xxx

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

**The application was built as a JAR file.**

Comment: Is your MySQL running as a RDS service? Assuming Yes -- did you set the Inbound Rules to let a connection from Elastic Beanstalk?  I have deployed a Spring BOOT app that uses RDS MySQL  to EB and this was one of the tasks that I had to do. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html

Comment: Yes. I can already successfully connect to the RDS MySQL. Locally in my SpringBoot application and/or using my workbench. Both work and run great. So I think it can't be because of that?!

Comment: As a test -- can you set the Inbound Rules to allow all traffic to rule out this is the issue blocking your app.

Comment: Ok, I did it - the problem is unfortunately not solved.

Comment: So your app runs fine locally and connect to RDS. But when you deploy to EB, you run into issues? I am going to re deploy my app that uses RDS on EB and make notes.

Comment: It is exactly like that. Thanks very much

Comment: In the logs you posted it looks like Nginx is saying it can't connect to your Spring Boot app. We really need to see the Spring Boot app logs to have any idea what is going on.

Comment: @Mark B I don't see any errors within my SpringBoot application. At least not locally. Where can I see this in AWS?

Comment: There should be more log files. Can you SSH into the server and view the logs? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html You might want to SSH into the server to see if the Java process is even running.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, I have my sample Spring BOOT app that uses MySQL RDS data and queries and displays data perfectly.

[image]

I am currently in the process of deploying to Elastic Beanstalk. I will update this thread with notes once done.

**UPDATE**

I successfully deployed this Spring BOOT app to Elastic Beanstalk and got the RDS Connection working. I packaged up the Spring BOOT app into a JAR by using **mvn package**. Then I deployed the JAR onto Elastic Beanstalk.

[image]

Notes:

Be sure to specify your environment variables correctly in the Elastic Beanstalk environment (as opposed to a Spring config file) -- as shown here:

[image]

The AWS Creds are needed if your app uses an AWS Service Client. I use SES in this app so I need them

Now here is the important part. You need to set the Inbound rules so that a connection from the app deployed on EB to RDS can be made. I simply used this for testing....

[image]

To take this further, you can of course use the IP Address of your app on Beanstalk in your Inbound Rule. To do so, get the IP of your Elastic Beanstalk app. Then use that IP in your inbound rule.

[image]

**Make sure that the Security Group your RDS uses is also the same Security Group your EB app uses. Both RDS and EB has to be in same region.**

Comment: I opened/allowed all traffic to RDS. Unfortunately still no change. How can I change the VCP group in meier EB aud diesel like my RDS?

Comment: Is your app rendering on EB?

Comment: Now I get the status "OK". But when I try to make a request I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. The port has been changed to 5000.

Comment: Nginx error log: 2022/04/07 14:15:11 [error] 12523#12523: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.91.94.70, server: , request: "GET /api/all HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/all", host: "syfall-env.eba-ma2gqjef.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2022/04/07 14:16:35 [error] 12523#12523: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.91.94.70, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "syfall-env.eba-ma2gqjef.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"

Comment: Find me on Linked IN. I can help you via an online meeting. I want to see your desktop as you do this.